# How to change label of a contact field with only the keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, contacts

In Apple Contacts, one can choose between several "labels" for each field in a contact, such as `work` and `home` for an email address, or `spouse` and `mother` for a related name. I'd like to use my keyboard to do this so that I can add contact information as fast as possible.

[image: choose a label for the email field]

As far as I know, I can navigate between fields by pressing <kbd>tab</kbd> on my keyboard, but I don't know how to change a label. I have to click on it.

How can I change a label using only my keyboard?

NB: It's insufficient to use templates as a workaround for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to system preferences , accessibility, voice over training, it teaches you how to move around screen and select controls all with using the keyboard.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that improves my speed.